# How to remove TaskBar/Navigation Bar when Modal popup appears?

Tags: android, navigation, taskbar, react-navigation-bottom-tab, android-bottomnav

Does anyone have any approach or known solution??

[Taskbar do not appear when user is at home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWmp2.png)
[Taskbar appears when modal popup is opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXR0C.png)

Platform: Android
Using: ReactNative
OS: 13 Android version
Rest are normal as all android system table.

I Have written this peice of code and I was able to disable the taskbar at homescreen.

`Navigation.setDefaultOptions({ navigationBar: { visible: false, },`

Now I am getting this Taskbar back when a popup/modal opens up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.